# Getting an error using a regular expression in my SQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am writing a query that gives me matches found to my regular expression in mysql. I have seen that REGEX is type we use to give our regular expression but after executing the query I get an error. I am not specifying a column for the WHERE condition as I want it to search in all columns What wrong am I doing?

I have written a simple query that returns * from the table where the regex matches.

```
select * from job WHERE REGEXP '^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$';
```

Expected output to be the entire row with its name and the column name as well for the matched REGEX. But the error I am getting is 
Amazon Invalid operation: type "regexp" does not exist; [SQL State=42704, DB Errorcode=500310]

Comment: If `REGEXP` is not supported, try `RLIKE`, and make sure to use a capturing group, just for  safety (`(`, not `(?:`).

Comment: RLIKE is not working too, says RLIKE does not exists

Comment: Try posix operators https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the regex. What error you see has nothing to do with that regex. I mean you could down scale it to its basic parts `^4[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9][0-9])?$` but that's not going to fix what's wrong with your/my sql.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic “search all columns” syntax; you must name them all:

```
select * from job
WHERE col1 REGEXP '^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$'
OR col2 REGEXP '^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$'
OR col3 ... etc
```

Comment: @sid what do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"? According to the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), it *should* work.

Comment: I know..but when I type "REGEXP" it doesnt show as a keyword , for example for "like". When I type "like" it turns into a blue color but not so for regexp

Comment: @Sidd I don't kow what tool/ide you're using for highlighting, but clearly it doesn't recognise all of mysql keywords. However, not highlighting as a keyword is irrelevant to there being a syntax error.

Comment: I am using sql workbench. Okay, but no matter in what syntax I try REGEXP is not getting executed

Comment: SQL Workbench is a generic tool that has basic highlighting for keywords of standard SQL. REGEXP is not part of that standard. Are you sure you’re using MySQL?

Comment: The data I wanted was in AWS redshift so REGEXP did not work for it. I used posix and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: If you're using redshift, why have you tagged your question with mysql?